# Finding nearest schools in Google Maps for post code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I search nearest schools for any given post code like shown in following screenshot?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXyUI.png

When I go to maps.google.com I don't see this option. Or is it only available through Google Maps API? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The Places API will do something like this. See the example at https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search and alter the code to change `"store"` to `"school"` (and the `location` to something else, if necessary).

The example you quote probably has their own database of schools.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew is exactly right. You'll need to call in places along with your maps.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

Basic setup:

```
 var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType); 
  // Places request
  // ALL TYPES: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types
  var request = {
    location: myLatLng,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['school']
  };
```

This example will need some modifying when put into use.

I had to do this recently for a project of mine (sorry for the annoying polygon in this example), here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/1kdd9ouo/1/).